# How to add a new value for x and y from another variable in javascript scatter chart?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, scatter

I'm having problem in inserting a value for and x and y. I want the value that I will insert in the array for x and y will come from a variable. I want to push another x and y in the array. I want to push a time value for x and a number y.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function () {
      var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",

      {
      title:{
        text: "Converting in Local Time"
      },

      axisX:{
        title: "time",
        gridThickness: 2,
        interval:1, 
        intervalType: "hour",        
        valueFormatString: "hh:MM", 
        labelAngle: -20
      },
      axisY:{
        title: "distance"
      },
      data: [
      {        
        type: "line",
        dataPoints: [//array
        {x: new Date( Date.UTC (2016, 0, 1, 1,0) ), y: 26 },
        {x: new Date( Date.UTC (2016, 0, 1,2,0) ), y: 38  },
        {x: new Date( Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1,3,0) ), y: 43 },

        ]}
      ]
    });
    chart.push({
        x:new Date( Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1,4,0) ),
        y:28
        });

chart.render();
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 50%;">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

*do not push in chart variable*

**try it**

```
chart.data.dataPoints.push( {x:new Date( Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1,4,0) ),y:28 });
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I get the value that I will insert in the x axis from another variable? For example: int val = 0; how do I insert the value of val into the x axis?

Comment: i can't understand what you want. you means push variable Val values into X variable?